# MySQL Query for finding distinct values in columns and getting the sum

Tags: mysql

I am having few Movie DVDs and want to create a simple database in MySQL. PF the DB structure. Am having a MySQL query which actually doesn't list out the exact no. of movies I am having. The query below is -

```
SELECT SUM(Total) as total
FROM (
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Movie1)) AS Total FROM tbl_movie 
      WHERE Movie1 !='' AND Movie1 IS NOT NULL AND DVDCategory='Movie'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Movie2)) FROM tbl_movie 
       WHERE Movie2 !='' AND Movie2 IS NOT NULL AND DVDCategory='Movie'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Movie3)) FROM tbl_movie 
       WHERE Movie3 !='' AND Movie3 IS NOT NULL AND DVDCategory='Movie'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Movie4)) FROM tbl_movie 
       WHERE Movie4 !='' AND Movie4 IS NOT NULL AND DVDCategory='Movie'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Movie5)) FROM tbl_movie 
       WHERE Movie5 !='' AND Movie5 IS NOT NULL AND DVDCategory='Movie'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Movie6)) FROM tbl_movie 
       WHERE Movie6 !='' AND Movie6 IS NOT NULL AND DVDCategory='Movie'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Movie7)) FROM tbl_movie 
       WHERE Movie7 !='' AND Movie7 IS NOT NULL AND DVDCategory='Movie'
) AS Total;
```

DB Structure -

```
ID DVD Movie1   Movie2   Movie3      Movie4          Movie5   Movie6   Movie7
__________________________________________________________________
1  1  IronMan  Movie11   MindHunters  300            Jumper   7        
2  2  IronMan2 Movie22   Grey         Blood Diamond
3  3  Movie33  Red Eye   Departed     300            
4  4  Movie44  Gladiator King Kong
5  5  Movie55  Hitman
```

It shows 13 results instead of 18 movies in DB. I searched your list of questions, but didn't find any suitable answer. Could you convey where am I going wrong or is there any better way I can arrange this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update -

You are going wrong with the `UNION`. It removes duplicates. Your inner queries are returning (5,5,4,2,1,1,0) but the union turns them into (5,4,2,1,0) after removing duplicates.

You need to use `UNION ALL` to count everything. Just replace all `UNION`s with `UNION ALL`

When you do, you will notice that if there are movies across columns i.e. if movie 300 was in column `Movie4` and `Movie5` for different users, it will count twice.

If you need to just get the distinct movies across all columns, get distinct movies from individual columns first, `UNION` them to remove duplicates and then count movies.

```
SELECT COUNT(movie) as total
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT Movie1 AS movie FROM tbl_movie 
    WHERE Movie1 !='' AND Movie1 IS NOT NULL AND DVDCategory='Movie'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT Movie2 FROM tbl_movie 
    WHERE Movie2 !='' AND Movie2 IS NOT NULL AND DVDCategory='Movie'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT Movie3 FROM tbl_movie 
     WHERE Movie3 !='' AND Movie3 IS NOT NULL AND DVDCategory='Movie'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT Movie4 FROM tbl_movie 
     WHERE Movie4 !='' AND Movie4 IS NOT NULL AND DVDCategory='Movie'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT Movie5 FROM tbl_movie 
     WHERE Movie5 !='' AND Movie5 IS NOT NULL AND DVDCategory='Movie'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT Movie6 FROM tbl_movie 
     WHERE Movie6 !='' AND Movie6 IS NOT NULL AND DVDCategory='Movie'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT Movie7 FROM tbl_movie 
     WHERE Movie7 !='' AND Movie7 IS NOT NULL AND DVDCategory='Movie'
) AS AllDistinctMovies;
```

Comment: I simply cannot express my feelings! What to say...Many thanx